# Efficient algorithm for finding the target sum

Tags: dynamic-programming, combinatorics, subset-sum

**Task.** Find such natural numbers a1,. . . , am , that none of them would be included in the list of excluded numbers, a1 + · · · + am = N and max{a1 , . . . , am} would be as small as possible. Numbers cannot be reused.

**Initial data.** The first line contains two natural numbers N and K - desired sum and length of excluded number list. The second line lists the K distinct numbers that are excluded.

**Results.** Output the numbers a1 , . . . , am, whose sum is N and which satisfy the listed conditions. They can be listed in any order. If it's impossible to satisfy the conditions, output "IMPOSSIBLE".

**Constraints.** 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 000 000, 0 ≤ K ≤ 1000 and all excluded number list members are between 1 and 1,000,000,000 inclusive.

This seems similar to the subset sum problem. I have implemented a tabular Dynamic Programming solution, however, that is not fast and memory-efficient enough. The time-complexity of my algorithm is O(N*(N-K)) while space-complexity is O(N).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you faithfully reported the problem statement ?

Answer (score 1):

This *is* an instance of the subset sum problem. The set is the range of naturals up to $N$ from which you remove the excluded numbers.

Comment: Which means that either your solution is wrong, or the estimated complexity is wrong.